# Gradle build fails with Google Service Plugin 3.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am attempting to update Google Services Plugin but receive an error during Gradle sync: 
**"Project Refresh Failed: Error: No Match Found"**

Everything works fine with Version 3.1.1 but as soon as I update the build.gradle to:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

the error occurs.

I checked the idea.log as the error suggested and can see that an exception is being thrown but I really do not know why.  It seems to get thrown at a method named "`getJsonLocations`" which seems to be new in 3.2.0 as shown in the image below.

[image]

Would anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: Do you have Java 8 installed?

Comment: Yes but my project settings are set to "Use Embedded JDK"

Comment: Seems to be related to `productFlavors'. If I remove my flavors then it works fine.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It seems that `productFlavours` must now start with a lower case letter for this plugin to work.  Using a capital letter throws the exception shown in the question.

I do not see this limitation documented.

```
productFlavors {

    // Works fine
    notDemo {
        applicationIdSuffix ".notDemo"
        versionNameSuffix "-notDemo"
    }

    // Not valid because it starts with a capital letter
    Demo {
        applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        versionNameSuffix "-demo"
    }
}
```

Reported : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72581499

Comment: OMG.                                   ______________________________________