# IllegalStateException: No match found while updating google-services to 3.2.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am not able to update my project to google-services 3.2.0. It is throwing an exception No match found. Check the logs below and help me out. Thanks.

Note: google-services 3.1.0 syncs perfectly fine, the problem occurs only with 3.2.0.

Logs:

> org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred
>   configuring project ':app'. at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found   at
>   java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536) at
>   java_util_regex_MatchResult$group.call(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.getJsonLocations(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:287)
>   at
>   com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.handleVariant(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:214)
>   at
>   com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$_setupPlugin_closure5.doCall(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:183)
>   at
>   com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.addVariant(AppExtension.java:79)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApiObjectFactory.create(ApiObjectFactory.java:132)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$6(BasePlugin.java:760)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:746)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:652)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:648)

Comment: Have you tried this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48523801/9389798 ?

Answer (score 0):

New Fcm update fixed this issue.
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'